# Webpack 2 uses 'use strict' twice and has a weird output pre-minification?

Tags: webpack

I am new to Webpack so I am not sure if the following output looks right?
I am already using `use strict` in my code and Webpack adds one of its own.

Furthermore, the non-minified output seems to be wrapped in an eval function. Usually I see transpiled ES6 code to be otherwise. Maybe something is not right?

[image]

Comment: Are you using `devtool: eval` or `devtool: eval-source-map` or something?

Comment: Since I am using Laravel Elixir, it goes like `devtool: Elixir.config.sourcemaps ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : '',` in their source code.

Comment: That's probably why you are seeing this then. Looks like you might be able to override.

Comment: Okay I removed it. The output is cleaner now and not enclosed in `eval` but I still see two use stricts by default. How do I turn this off? Looks like Webpack is the culprit here. I am already adding one myself, so Webpack should know..

Comment: What is the actual problem of having two `use strict` declarations?

Comment: @robertklep Doesn't look nice when you have OCD...

Comment: But, it's bundled code. It doesn't look nice to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

#### Regarding `use strict`

Webpack 1 and 2 does not add `"use strict"` to your code. It is caused by your specific loader or plugin setup. Babel, for instance, is known to add `"use strict"` at the beginning of the code. If you want to find the culprit, just remove loaders and plugins one at a time and observe, how the output changes.

#### Regarding "weird output"

As already mentioned in the comments: You are using the `devtool` option which enables you to view and debug your files in the browser exactly like you see it in your code editor. It is a common browser feature that is meant to map your code to actual source files – otherwise you would need to debug one big JavaScript file with code in it, that has not been written by you.

As described in the devtool options, only a few devtool options are recommended to use in production code (`source-map`, `cheap-module-source-map`, `cheap-source-map`) because they are slow or they add the original source code to the bundle which may not be desired. The production-ready devtools only add a comment to your bundled code with an URL to the actual source map.

Comment: I am using Buble instead of Babel, will check.